# Python connected to PostgreSql Redshift database, trying to run permission sequel but unable to. How can I grant permission or run permission query?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift, navicat

I'm trying to run a query using Python connected to PostgreSql using psycopg2. I'm able to connect but unable to run a query that gives permission which starts with 'grant select on ...'

I have tried doing regular 'select * from column limit 1' to see if the connection is made and that I'm able to do regular queries. I've tried 'grant select on view to user' but is not working.

```
permissions = "grant select on view_activities to username;"

try:
    cur.execute(permissions)
    contents = "The permissions have been run"
    message = twilioCli.messages.create(body = contents, from_=twil, to = me)
except:
    contents = "The permissions have failed"
    message = twilioCli.messages.create(body = contents, from_=twil, to = me)
```

The expected result is receiving a text message stating 'The permissions have been run' which indicates that this query has run without an issue. However, I'm getting the second result 'The permissions have failed' instead, which shows me that the query is not being run correctly. My theory is that postgres is unable to run Python's 'grant select...' syntax.

Comment: I have run similar queries using psycopg2 in the past, can you try disabling the exception handling or just print what exact execption is thrown, and then edit your answer (also comment below tagging my username when you do that so that I'll know). 
I'd be able to help once you get the exception message.

Comment: @Yankee I printed out the exception and I believe it says 'psycopg2.ProgrammingError: no results to fetch'. It seems like nothing is being returned so the rows get nothing. So is this what's breaking it? A query doesn't have to always return something since we can create/insert/update tables without having to return rows. Not sure how I can get this grant permission query to run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like some part of your code(which is maybe not added here), is executing `cursor.fetchall()` and `cursor.fetchone()`, which gives the same exception for me `psycopg2.ProgrammingError: no results to fetch` . Once I removed the `.fetchall()` or `.fetchone()` , my code executed without any issues.

Also, make sure you run `connection.commit()` after executing the `GRANT`, otherwise it'll be rolled back.